# Independence of increments of the stochastic process $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t u dW_u $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, stochastic, wienerprocess

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process such that

$$X_{t} =\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t u dW_u $$

I know that for

$$Y_{t} =\int_0^t u dW_u$$
$Y_t-Y_s$ is independent of $Y_s$ where $t>s$.
But is this also true for $X_t$ which has explicit time dependence in it?
Edit
The covariance is 
$$E[X_tX_s] - E[X_s^2]$$

$$E[X_t X_s] =\frac{1}{ts} \cdot E\biggl[\int_t^s u dW_u \int_0^s u dW_u\biggr] +E\biggl[\int_0^s u dW_u \int_0^s dW_u\biggr]  $$
The first integral in the first expectation  is limit of sequence of normal random variables which are independent of the second one and thus first  expectation can be split and using wiener process properties it vanishes.

Comment: is this a duplicate of your recently asked question?

Comment: @Attack68 no it's not a duplicate that one is about the probability distribution of X_t this one is about the   properties of X_t itself

Comment: Since each increment is normally distributed with mean $0$, you can check if the increments are bivariate normal (check if linear combinations of them are also going to be normal) and then check that the covariance of the increments is $0$. This would imply that the increments are independent since uncorrelated bivariate normal random variables are independent.

Comment: @Slade Thanks I checked the covariance it doesn't vanish unless s=t or s=0 ( trivial cases).  Thus X_t  doesn't have independent increments unlike Y_t

Comment: When you multiply the two stochastic integrals together they don't have any overlap in their integral limits. Did you account for this? If you edit your post with your attempt someone can check it out easier.

Comment: @Slade yes they don't have overlap in their integral limits but if you split it into overlapping and non overlapping part then expectation of non overlapping part vanishes becasue of properties of wiener process

Comment: The work that you posted is not calculating the covariance of two separate increments. Even for the case of $Y_t$ that you posted, calculating the covariance as you did would not lead to independence

Comment: @Slade here I showed  it for X_t-X_s and X_s-X_0 .t>s. X_0=0. I showed only partial calculations

Comment: I'll post something to clarify later today if no one else does

Comment: @Thanks also could you please point me to some resources for the proof that uncorrelated bivaraiate normal random variables are independent?

Comment: Something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897221/two-gaussian-random-variables-x-y-are-uncorrelated-if-and-only-if-they-are-ind

Comment: @bentenyson so the answer from Gordon below is how the calculation should be done. If the covariance had been $0$ then we could assert independence but since it's not then of course the increments aren't independent.

Comment: @Slade but that's precisely what I said in my previous  comment you split into overlapping and non overlapping part and non overallapping part is independent and vanishes. thus only the  overallapping part contributes and covariance isn't zero.

Comment: Ah I see. I think I may have misunderstood then. Anyway, hope it's clearer now

Comment: @Slade just one thing that's bothering me how can I formally show that \int_s^t u dW_u is independent of X_s? I mean if both integrals were replaced by finite sums then yes but what about their limit?

Comment: The process is basically the same as whatever you did for this problem. Something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978631/integrated-brownian-motion-independent-stationary-increments

Comment: @Slade Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, for $t>s>0$,
\begin{align*}
X_t-X_s &= \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t udW_u - \frac{1}{s}\int_0^s udW_u\\
&=\frac{1}{t}\bigg(\int_s^t u dW_u + \int_0^s udW_u \bigg)- \frac{1}{s}\int_0^s udW_u\\
&=\frac{1}{t} \int_s^t u dW_u + \Big(\frac{1}{t} -\frac{1}{s}\Big)\int_0^s udW_u\\
&=\frac{1}{t} \int_s^t u dW_u - \frac{t-s}{t} X_s.
\end{align*}
Here, $\int_s^t u dW_u$ is independent of $X_s$. Then
\begin{align*}
E\big((X_t-X_s) X_s \big) &= -\frac{t-s}{t} E\big(X_s^2\big) \ne 0.
\end{align*}
That is, $X_t-X_s$ is not independent of $X_s$.

Comment: @is there a formal way to show that $\int_s^t u dW_u$ is independent of X_s? I mean if both integrals were replaced by finite sums then yes but what about their limit?

Comment: As I am aware of, no.